# Is it possible send some JSON to a server when making a client side redirect?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

I want to be able to make a client side redirect while sending some kind of data to my server, that I rather not include in the url. Is this possible? If so how? And/Or is there a better way of going about this?

Thanks

**Edit:**

To be more clear, I prefer not solve this with making a POST request with a form, but this probably will be what I will end doing if I don't find a more suitable solution. (correct me if I'm wrong, but) I just don't believe it's semantically correct behaviour of a POST request, so I am looking for an alternative that doesn't feel as hacky.

I also noticed some suggested I use window.location in a callback of a ajax request. I won't be doing this as It's not as robust/restrictive enough for my case, and I want certain pages to only to be accessible under accessible under certain conditions.

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Why don't you simply submit a normal post request to whatever the destination url is (i.e. submit a normal form).

Comment: Like I said in response to @Pouki 's response it just, I was thinking about this, but it just feels semantically wrong, but it seems like the only solution up to this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a form with data you want to pass (with hidden fields and method post), then instead to use a redirect, simulate a submittion of the form using `$("#form").submit()`.

NB : The form has to have the action URL of the redirection.

Comment: The only reason I haven't gone with this earlier as it just feels semantically wrong to retrieve a web page with a POST request, and I was hoping for an alternative. But is the closet thing to what I'm looking for.

Comment: So, maybe there is an alternative, tell me what data should be passed and why it is "mandatory" for you ? :)

Comment: It's basically an identifier that redirects a user to a page on login, with certain conditions are meet. The normal login by default does not redirect the user (it's a modal that simply disappears). I realise could be solved with sessions, but I don't consider them ideal in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest,

Use a JS function, rather than an anchor tag or form action to redirect the page, call another function(ajax) to send some data before redirection by the same function... Sample code:

```
function redirect(url){
 ajaxFunctionCall();
 document.location=url;
}
```

Just take the ref. from the above code, it's not tested.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
var arr = { City: 'Moscow', Age: 25 };

$.ajax({
    url: 'get_params.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(arr),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(msg) {
        // success! if is needed //alert(msg);
        // redirect to your page
        window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah this was my initial idea, but I decided it wasn't appropriate for  my case it (see edit).